Confidence Interval of Continuous Statistic Model

Let $(\mathcal{X}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^d, \mathcal{F}=\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)\vert_{\mathcal{X}},\{P_{\vartheta}|\vartheta \in \Theta\})$ be a continuous statistic model, $\rho:\mathcal{X}\times \Theta \to[0,\infty)$ the corresponding likelihood funktion. You can construct the confidence interval for a given error level $\alpha\in (0,1)$ using the following method:
(i) $\forall c \in \mathbb{R}, \vartheta\in\Theta: C_c^{\vartheta}:=\{x\in\mathcal{X}\mid \rho(x,\vartheta)\geq c\}\in\mathcal{F}$
(ii)$\forall\vartheta\in\Theta: c(\vartheta):=\sup\{c\in \mathbb{R}| \ P_{\vartheta}(C_c^{\vartheta})\geq 1-\alpha\} \in [0,\infty)$
(iii) $\forall\vartheta\in\Theta: P_{\vartheta}(C_{\vartheta})\geq 1-\alpha \ $ for $C_{\vartheta}:=C_{c(\vartheta)}^{\vartheta} $
(iv) The mapping $C:\mathcal{X}\to\mathcal{P}(\Theta), C(x):=\{\vartheta\in\Theta\mid x\in C_{\vartheta}\}$ is a confidence interval for $id_{\Theta}$ to $\alpha$.

I am trying to prove (i) - (iv), maybe someone can tell me whether my proofs of (i),(ii) and (iv) are correct and tell me why (iii) holds.

(i): As the statistic model is continuous the density $\rho_{\vartheta}$ is Lebesgue-measurable and therefore $C_c^{\vartheta}=\rho_{\vartheta}^{-1}([c,\infty))\in\mathcal{F}$

(ii): First I want to show that $c(\vartheta)\geq 0$:
$P(C_0^{\vartheta})=P(\{x\in\mathcal{X}\mid \rho(x,\vartheta)\geq 0\})=P(\mathcal{X})=1\geq 1-\alpha \Rightarrow 0\in\{c\in \mathbb{R}| \ P_{\vartheta}(C_c^{\vartheta})\geq 1-\alpha\} \Rightarrow sup\{c\in \mathbb{R}| \ P_{\vartheta}(C_c^{\vartheta})\geq 1-\alpha\}\geq 0$
To show that $c(\vartheta)<\infty$ I use monotony and the continuity from above. It is easy to see that $C_{c_1}^{\vartheta}\supseteq C_{c_2}^{\vartheta}\ \forall c_1<c_2$ and therefore $\exists N\geq 1: P(C_{n}^{\vartheta})<1-\alpha\ \forall n\geq N $ and because of the monotony also $\forall c\in\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $c\geq N$.

(iii): For this I have to show that $c(\vartheta)$ defined as the supremum over the set $\{c\in \mathbb{R}| \ P_{\vartheta}(C_c^{\vartheta})\geq 1-\alpha\}$ lies in said set. I think this should be easy but I'm clearly missing something here. My first guess would have been to somehow argue with continuity, but I don't know how.

(iv): I have to show that $\forall \vartheta\in\Theta: \ P_{\vartheta}(\{x\in\mathcal{X}\mid \vartheta\in C(x)\})\geq 1-\alpha$.
This follows directly from the definition of $C$ and (iii) as $\{x\in\mathcal{X}\mid \vartheta\in C(x)\}=\{x\in\mathcal{X}\mid x\in C_{c(\vartheta)}\}=C_{c(\vartheta)}$ and according to (iii) $P_{\vartheta}(C_{c(\vartheta)})\geq 1-\alpha$.


Edit: Maybe someone could also show me the application of this method considering $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),\{P_{\vartheta} |\vartheta\in\Theta:=\mathbb{R}\})$, $P_{\vartheta}$ absolutely continuous with respect to $\lambda^1$ with density $\rho_{\vartheta}(x)=e^{-(x-\vartheta)}\cdot\mathbb{1}_{[\vartheta,\infty)}(x)$
